# no such Table SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Im having some trouble with creating a database in SQLite in android.. Here i initiliaze the keys:

```
public final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public final String KEY_CategoryId = "CategoryId";
public final String KEY_DealerAddress = "DealerAddress";
public final String KEY_DealerCity = "DealerCity";
public final String KEY_DealerCountry = "DealerCountry";
public final String KEY_DealerLatitude = "DealerLatitude";
public final String KEY_DealerLongitude = "DealerLongitude";
public final String KEY_DealerName = "DealerName";
public final String KEY_DealerWeb = "DealerWeb";
public final String KEY_DealerPhone = "DealerPhone";
public final String KEY_DealerZip = "DealerZip";
public final String KEY_Description = "Description";
public final String KEY_EndDate = "EndDate";
public final String KEY_EndTime = "EndTime";
public final String KEY_Id = "Id";
public final String KEY_Name = "Name";
public final String KEY_PriceBefore = "PriceBefore";
public final String KEY_PriceNow = "PriceNow";
public final String KEY_SavingInPercent = "SavingInPercent";
public final String KEY_StartDate = "StartDate";
public final String KEY_StartTime = "StartTime";
private final String TAG = "DataBase";

private final String DATABASE_NAME = "DealFinders";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Favorites";
private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
    "CategoryId text not null,"
    + "DealerAddress text not null, DealerCity text not null, DealerCountry text not null, " +
    "DealerLatitude text not null, DealerLongitude text not null, DealerName text not null," +
    "DealerWeb text not null, DealerPhone text not null,Description text not null," +
    "EndDate text not null,EndTime text not null,Id text not null,Name text not null," +
    "PriceBefore text not null, PriceNow text not null, SavingInPercent text not null, " +
    "StartDate text not null, StartTime text not null);";
```

And the rest is like this http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954 , ofcourse with some input changes. But it keeps giving no such table?? i have tried to change the table name but it didnt help..

I cant see what the problem should be?? when i tried out the tutorial it worked just fine but now it giving some troubles?? Any ideas??

The problem is when inserting values into the database:

```
id = db.insertTitle(
                        "nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej",
                        "nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej","nej",
                        "C# 2008 Programmer's Reference",
                        "Wrox");
```

The error is:

```
01-02 20:18:51.512: E/Database(15601): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: 
favorites: , while compiling: INSERT INTO favorites(DealerPhone, Description, DealerCity, 
PriceNow, DealerAddress, SavingInPercent, DealerCountry, PriceBefore, DealerName, Name, 
DealerWeb, EndDate, DealerLongitude, DealerLatitude, CategoryId, StartDate, Id, EndTime, 
StartTime, DealerZip) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: Can you post the statement that gives the exception? Your code does not contain enough information...

Comment: I have giving where the error shows up and the error from the log cat.. Hopefully this will give a better meaning..

Comment: I'm downvoting this question and voting for it to be closed as "too localised". Please use Stack Overflow for questions that you can't answer yourself. It is not a platform for people to help you debug your tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Well, the executed statement is

```
INSERT INTO favorites ...
```

Whereas you probably want to

```
INSERT INTO titles ...
```

I'm guessing that either your `DATABASE_TABLE` or `DATABASE_CREATE` constant is wrong... You should've found this out yourself, though

Comment: No i actually found out what the mistake is.. Let me tell you it wasnt that easy to find.. In Android once you use a name for a Table e.g. TITLE like the one from the tutorial YOU CANT change it.. You have to delete the application from you phone to do it.. Thanks for been SOOO heelpfull..

Comment: Well that's normal. Infact when you made some upgrade to your databse and you release a patch, you have to manage that upgrades making changes to old tables or it will crash on old app version

Comment: It seems to have alot of work in it.. But now it works.. Thanks

Comment: Lukas how can i be able to ask questions again?? ive read that i have to change my question?? but i dont know what i can change it to?? Help me and in furture i will be better to ask questions that can be answered and be helpful for everybody.

Comment: @Mustii1989: I've rolled back your change. This question here is not going to be useful for future users, especially if you change it heavily. But feel free to ask a new, more specific question! Also, if you're not sure about what went wrong with this one, you can ask people on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to help you how to improve your question quality

Comment: But how can i begin asking questions again?? im not able to ask new questions any more??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its pretty clear. You are trying to insert a value into the table favorites but your create String has tiles.

Its either one of those. Maybe you are a victim a furious copy/paste.